# How to save multiple labels of a node in neo4j in a specified order?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I use py2neo to create a node, which has three labels ('photograph', 'creativework', 'thing'), and stores them in neo4j in the order of those labels.
In the follow-up work, I will use the first label, which is'photograph'.

But the order in which the label of the node is displayed in neo4j is as follows:

[image]

And the order of the nodes retrieved by py2neo is also wrong, the first label becomes 'creativework', which is not to my liking.
So how to save multiple labels of a node in neo4j in a specified order?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify the problem? There are times when analytics or visualizations benefit from multiple labels. I'm making some assumption by creating the framework (which you should do in future questions). Is this your scenario? I've added another Label "Node"

```
create (n1:Node)
create (n2:Node)
create (n3:Node)

with n1,n2,n3
match (n1) set n1:CreativeWork 
with n1,n2,n3
match (n1) set n1:ImageProject 
with n1,n2,n3
with n1,n2,n3
match (n1) set n1:MediaProject 
with n1,n2,n3
match (n1) set n1:Thing 

with n1,n2,n3
match (n2) set n1:CreativeWork 
with n1,n2,n3
match (n2) set n1:ImageProject 
with n1,n2,n3
match (n2) set n1:MediaProject 
with n1,n2,n3
match (n2) set n1:Thing 

with n1,n2,n3
match (n3) set n1:CreativeWork 
with n1,n2,n3
match (n3) set n1:MediaProject
```

If so, what is it you're trying to do. The display you showed is the node labels are they would appear in the results window after running a query.There is not a way to change that sort order. But why is that sort important to you? It's not something an end user will see. You actually have only 3 nodes and they would all be visualized similarly.

Can you achieve you goal using properties? If not every node has 3Labels, then you could use a grass file to distinguish them. The grass file processes the formatting by the order (bottom to top) the nodes appear in the listing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will simplify my question.----> "If I store multiple tags for a node at once (create(n:B:A:D:C)), neo4j seems to automatically correct the order of these tags in ascending lexicographical order ((n:A:B:C: D)), is there a way to prevent neo4j from doing this?" I look forward to your answer

Comment: I don't think you can do this within the Neo4j browser displays without getting into the inner workings of the java code. You could use some prefix _ or __ (2_)  to get the effect, but then this would carry through to all your querying. I'm still not sure exactly why, from an analytic perspective, this is important.